# WebSocket connection failed. Error during WebSocket handshake - socketjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

**Details:**

I have been trying to configure my react project to work with `hot loader` so that I can actively develop without having to restart the server.  I am getting a continuous error message each time websocket tries to connect:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.33.10/sockjs-node/301/eo4p2zps/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404` .  My gut tells me it might have to do with my VM (vagrant) which runs Ubuntu -v `14.04.3`.  In addition to the above error logged, I get:

```
http://192.168.33.10/sockjs-node/629/s0dz3nxv/xhr_streaming?t=1482558136743 404 (Not Found)
http://192.168.33.10/sockjs-node/629/jbjciaga/eventsource 404 (Not Found)
http://192.168.33.10/sockjs-node/iframe.html 404 (Not Found)
http://192.168.33.10/sockjs-node/629/e1x0l01e/xhr?t=1482558137388 404 (Not Found)
Warning: [react-router] Location "/sockjs-node/629/dr44jysd/htmlfile?c=_jp.ajy5ad3" did not match any routes
client?e2df:41 [WDS] Disconnected!
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I've also taken the following boilerplate: https://github.com/jpsierens/webpack-react-redux in hopes to compare my current configuration but, both seem to be proper.

**Configurations**

`webpack.config.js`:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:80/',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.js')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: 'app/index.tpl.html',
          inject: 'body',
          filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ],
    eslint: {
        configFile: '.eslintrc',
        failOnWarning: false,
        failOnError: false
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'eslint'
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json?$/,
                loader: 'json'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style!css!sass?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]'
            },
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'file' }
        ]
    }
};
```

`server.js`

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    // It suppress error shown in console, so it has to be set to false.
    quiet: false,
    // It suppress everything except error, so it has to be set to false as well
    // to see success build.
    noInfo: false,
    stats: {
      // Config for minimal console.log mess.
      assets: false,
      colors: true,
      version: false,
      hash: false,
      timings: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }
}).listen(8080, 'localhost', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

  console.log('Listening at localhost:8080');
});
```

**Addition**

Also see a more `graphical` output of my errors:

[image: Error console output]

**Conclusion**

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or ideas.  If I can provide any more details, let me know.

Comment: I had a similar issue running a MQTT client over web sockets on the browser. I solved this by re-confugering the ports. There were 2 ports one for IPv4 and one for IPv6. I only had to use one.

Comment: Interesting, I think that maybe the `webpack-dev-server` is being blocked potentially.  Let me look at the port configuration.

Answer (score 16):

Okay, I know what I'm about to say is weird, but that's what happened to mine.

**I assume you're using nginx proxy**. and ' `Error during WebSocket handshake - socketjs`' has nothing to do with chrome browser or websocket (ws) script. It was the same error in firefox. After (really) a while, I figured out 'ws' scripts are in order and it has something to do with proxy. It goes to '404' as if there was no response from websocket.

and, I tried to set my nginx proxy location as,

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    #proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

and this works. a proxy setting to nginx must specify header host, connection at least.
i commented out the `proxy_set_header` since the $host variable could be different at your end.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. My nginx.conf was nearly identical except that I didn't have `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";`. Thanks!

Comment: Worked perfectly, thousand thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with websockets and nginx and i think the issue might be proxy too. I don't get any error past 'WebSocket connection to 'ws://hostip/websocket' failed:' and my nginx setting doesnt look like yours. it has similar settings but they are for location /api and location /grafana. but the location / has only root and try_files. do you think i need a setting for location /websockets ?

Comment: Thanks to Joe Sadoski. `proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";` was helpfull for me.